# Should client check postcondition/should called method check precondition?

Tags: domain-driven-design, preconditions, post-conditions

The *preconditions* and the *postconditions* of the public method form a contract between this method and its client.

1.According [to](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/oop-csharp/html/notes/contracts_themes-contract-sect.html), *caller* shouldn't verify *postcondition* and *called method* shouldn't verify *preconditions*:

> Let us recall the precondition and the postcondition of the square
>   root function sqrt, as shown in Program 49.2. A function that calls
>   sqrt is responsible to pass a non-negative number to the function. If
>   a negative number is passed, the square root function should do
>   nothing at all to deal with it. If, on the other hand, a non-negative
>   number is passed to sqrt, it is the responsibility of sqrt to deliver
>   a result which fulfills the postcondition. Thus, the caller of sqrt
>   should do nothing at all to check or rectify the result.
>
> Blame the caller if a precondition of an operation fails 
>   Blame the called operation if the postcondition of an operation fails

But as seen in code included in [another article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2006/09/22/Design_2D00_by_2D00_Contract_3A00_-A-Practical-Introduction.aspx), *called method* does verify *preconditions*:

```
/// <summary>Gets the user for the given ID.</summary>
public User GetUserWithIdOf(int id,
        UserRepository userRepository) {
  // Pre-conditions
  if (userRepository == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(
          "userRepository");
  if (id <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
          "id must be > 0");

  User foundUser = userRepository.GetById(id);

  // Post-conditions
  if (foundUser == null)
      throw new KeyNotFoundException("No user with " +
          "an ID of " + id.ToString() +
          " could be located.");

  return foundUser;
}
```

a) Since it is a responsibility of a *client* to fulfill the *preconditions* of a method, should  *called method* also check whether *preconditions* are fulfilled?

b) Since it is a responsibility of a *called method* to deliver result which fulfills the *postcondition*, should the *caller* check the *postcondition*?

2.One of the benefits mentioned in first article is that *"Preconditions and postconditions can be used to divide the responsibility between classes in OOP"*, which I understand as also saying that it isn't the responsibility of *called method* to verify *preconditions* and it isn't the responsibility of a *caller* to verify *postcondition*.

But doesn't adhering to such philosophy make our code more vulnerable, since it blindly trusts that the other party ( other party being either a *caller* or a *method* ) will deliver on its promise?

3.If caller/called method doesn't blindly trust other party , then don't we loose much of the benefits provided by *postconditions* and *preconditions*, since now *called method* must take on the responsibility to also check *precondition* and *caller* must take on responsibility to verify the *postcondition*?

thanks

**EDIT**

3.

> > If caller/called method doesn't blindly trust other party , then don't
> >     we loose much of the benefits provided by postconditions and
> >     preconditions, since now called method must take on the responsibility
> >     to also check precondition and caller must take on responsibility to
> >     verify the postcondition?
>
> Caller does not need to verify post-conditions because they should be
>   ensured by the called method. Called method does need to verify
>   pre-conditions because there is not other way to enforce the contract.

a) Are you assuming that *postcondition* should only ever state/guarantee that a *return value* is of specified type or `null` (if  *return value* is *nullable*)? Besides of what type the *return value* will be, can't *postconditions* also state other things ( which can't be verified by type system ), like whether *return value* is within *specified range* ( example: can't *postcondition* also state that *return value* of type `int` will be within the range of `10-20` )? Wouldn't in this case client need to also check for *postcondition*?

b) Can we say then that first article is wrong with its claims that *called method* shouldn't check *preconditions*?

**2. EDIT**

> No, a post condition can be anything, not just a null check. Either
>   way, the client can assume that the post-condition has been verified
>   so that, for example, you don't need to verify the int range if the
>   contract states that it has been ensured.

a) You previously stated that *preconditions* need to be checked by *called method* in order  to make code less vulnerable, but couldn't we also reason that *caller* needs to verify a *postcondition* ( e.g. verify that returned `int` value is within range promised by *postcondition* ) in order to make *caller's code* less vulnerable?

b) If client can blindly trust claims made by *postcondition* ( I'd say it is a blind trust when *postcondition* makes claims like *return value is within some range* ), why can't *called method* also trust that *caller* will fulfill called method's *preconditions*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a) Since it is a responsibility of a client to fulfill the
>   preconditions of a method, should called method also check whether
>   preconditions are fulfilled?

Yes, it is the responsibility of the client to ensure preconditions are satisfied, however the called method must verify this, hence the null checks in the example.

> b) Since it is a responsibility of a called method to deliver result
>   which fulfills the postcondition, should the caller check the
>   postcondition?

The caller should be able to depend on the contract of the called method. In the example you provided, the method `GetUserWithIdOf` ensures the post-condition is met, throwing an exception otherwise. The repository itself doesn't have a post-condition that it will always return a user, as a user may not be found.

> 2.One of the benefits mentioned in first article is that "Preconditions and postconditions can be used to divide the
>   responsibility between classes in OOP", which I understand as also
>   saying that it isn't the responsibility of called method to verify
>   preconditions and it isn't the responsibility of a caller to verify
>   postcondition.

It is still the responsibility of the called method to verify pre-conditions because they can't usually be verified by the type system. Languages such as [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29) provide a greater degree of static contract verification, in which case one can utilize the language to enforce pre-conditions. Just like in Java/C# you can enforce that a method parameter is of a given type, Eiffel extends this type of verification to more complex contract declarations.

> But doesn't adhering to such philosophy make our code more vulnerable,
>   since it blindly trusts that the other party ( other party being
>   either a caller or a method ) will deliver on its promise?

Yes, which is why pre-conditions must be verified.

> 3.If caller/called method doesn't blindly trust other party , then don't we loose much of the benefits provided by postconditions and
>   preconditions, since now called method must take on the responsibility
>   to also check precondition and caller must take on responsibility to
>   verify the postcondition?

Caller does not need to verify post-conditions because they should be ensured by the called method. Called method does need to verify pre-conditions because there is not other way to enforce the contract.

**UPDATE**

a) No, a post condition can be anything, not just a null check. Either way, the client can assume that the post-condition has been verified so that, for example, you don't need to verify the int range if the contract states that it has been ensured.

b) I would say so yes. To quote:

> If a negative number is passed, the square root function should do
>   nothing at all to deal with it.

The *if* suggests that the called method already does some sort of verification. Doing nothing at all is a silent fail, which can be an [anti-pattern](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/validation-throw-exceptions-early.html).

A subsequent quote:

> Blame the caller if a precondition of an operation fails Blame the
>   called operation if the postcondition of an operation fails

The only way to blame the caller for a failed pre-condition is to first determine that a pre-condition has failed. Since the called method "owns" this pre-condition, it should be the last stop to flag the failure.

**UPDATE 2**

a,b) The reason a caller can trust post-conditions is because post-conditions can be ensured by the called method. The called method is what declares and owns the contract. The reason that the called method can't trust caller is because there nobody that guarantees that pre-conditions will be met. The called method doesn't know about all the various callers that it may have, therefore it has to verify on its own.

Comment: That's reasonable argument. But if your code called a method on a class written by some novice programmer, would you trust the called method ( i.e. trust this novice programmer ) to fulfill the promised postconditions or do you put trust ( i.e. you, the caller, don't check the postconditions ) only in methods written by "excerpts"?

Comment: If you're calling code you can't trust then yes you must re-verify post-conditions too. This is especially true for external systems. But if you're calling local code that has tests, then you should be able to rely on the contract. Otherwise, what is the point of contracts?